# Why doesn't the Floyd-Warshall algorithm work if I put k in the innermost loop

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

The Floyd-Warshall algorithm is defined as follows:

```
   for k from 1 to |V|
      for i from 1 to |V|
         for j from 1 to |V|
            if dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] then
               dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
```

Why doesn't it work if I simply use

```
for i from 1 to |V|
  for j from 1 to |V|
     for k from 1 to |V|
        if dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] then
           dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
```

In this case, the intermediate node k is iterated in the innermost loop. I expect it will make the same comparisons, but maybe different order. Why is the result different and incorrect?

Comment: What does this one do? `next[i][j] ← k`

Comment: maybe to remember the path.. I just copied from wikipedia. We can I ignore it I guess, I am not interested in that part

Comment: It is incorrect because the ordering is incorrect. The "different order" is what makes it incorrect.

Comment: [Incorrect implementations of the Floyd--Warshall algorithm give correct solutions after three repeats](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01210)

Answer (score 6):

Take $i - 1$ and $j = 2$. The algorithm is trying to find the shortest path between $1$ and $2$, by considering intermediate vertices. But at this point, most of the array dist is infinity, so we don't even find that $2$ is reachable from $1$ unless the distance is $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 4):

The approach of the algorithm is dynamic programming. This means that during computation only partial solutions are determined. Here $k$ is an important parameter in the algorithm. When dealing with $k$, shortest paths are computed that are only allowed to pass vertices $1$ upto $k$, the other vertices can only be initial or final. That means that $k$ has a different position than that of $i,j$. We cannot change that order. For a fixed $k$ however, the values $i,j$ within the inner two loops can be evaluated in ant order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example when `for k` being the inner most loop doesn't work:

0 -- 2 -- 3 -- 1

Say each edge weight is 1. The corresponding adjacency matrix is:

| Node | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | inf | 1 | inf |
| 1 | inf | 0 | inf | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | inf | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | inf | 1 | 1 | 0 |

The final distance for 0 and 1 is inf, which is incorrect:

```
dist[0][1] = min(inf, dist[0][1]+dist[1][1], dist[0][2]+dist[2][1], dist[0][3]+dist[3][1])
           = min(inf, inf, inf, inf)
           = inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially

```
dist[i][j] = AdjacentMatrix[i][j] //all directly reachable nodes are the base case.
```

How more can we improve on the base case?

Two possible algorithms which can work.

1. Find `dist[i][j] = For all k { dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] }`

   This doesn't work because `dist[i][k]` can still be `INF` and is not finalized.
2. Fix one intermediate node `k1` & find all `dist[i][j]` passing through intermediate node.

   On the second intermediate node `k2`,
   Find `dist[i][j] = min { dist[i][k1] + dist[k1][j] , dist[i][k2] + dist[k2][j] }`

   In this algorithm, although `dist[i][k]` is not finalized, it is OK. 
   Because value of `dist[i][j]` is finalized only when `dist[i][kn]` is compared.