# Can I change the order of iteratorion in the Floyd-Warshall Algorithm?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I am studying how Floyd-Warshall works and came across this doubt.
In the code:

```
for(int k = 0; k < V; k++)
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            Matrix[i][j] = min(Matrix[i][j], Matrix[i][k] + Matrix[k][j]);
```

I can see I can not change order of `k` because it is the intermediate vertex. The order of `i` and `j`, on the other hand, seems like don't necessarily need to be in that position.

Am I wrong?  All I can see is that they are just the combination of pairs with `k` in the middle.

Comment: Look at the proof of why Floyd-Warshall works as is. Try switching two of the for loops - does the proof still hold?

Comment: For reference, a *different*, but related question is [Why doesn't the Floyd-Warshall algorithm work if I put k in the innermost loop](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/why-doesnt-the-floyd-warshall-algorithm-work-if-i-put-k-in-the-innermost-loop).