# Can the loops be in any order in the Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I have a question about the Floyd Warshall algorithm. Here is the code from the Wikipedia page:

```
let dist be a |V| × |V| array of minimum distances initialized to ∞ (infinity)
for each edge (u, v) do
    dist[u][v] ← w(u, v)  // The weight of the edge (u, v)
for each vertex v do
    dist[v][v] ← 0
for k from 1 to |V|
    for i from 1 to |V|
        for j from 1 to |V|
            if dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] 
                dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
            end if
```

Our professor told us that the loop for k MUST be outside the i and j loops. I am unable to understand why this must be the case. He said that if k is inside we will only compute the best 2 edged or 1 edge path from i to j. I just don't see it. Can someone help?

Comment: Your professor is right that $k$ needs to be outside (check the correctness proof to see why), but wrong about the description of the output. It is only correct for $(i,j)=(1,2)$.

Comment: Sorry I misquoted him, now I have corrected it. But could you please write why k needs to be outside?

Comment: Are you familiar with the analysis of Floyd–Warshall? Would the analysis work when $k$ is inside?

Comment: That is what I am unsure of.

Comment: The professor is still wrong about what happens when $k$ is inside. When $(i,j) = (1,2)$ you are computing the best path of length at most $2$, but you are then allowed to use this best path for further computations.

Comment: Are you familiar with the analysis of Floyd–Warshall? If not, that would be a great thing to review.

Comment: By analysis, do you mean a correctness proof?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117327/discussion-between-user123215321631443-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: Right, the correctness proof. Time complexity is trivial for Floyd–Warshall.

Comment: Even without understanding the complete analysis, you can check that what the professor said is correct for $(i,j) = (1,2)$. This is already enough to show that the modified algorithm is wrong.

Comment: So when (i, j) =  (1 , 2), that would mean that if k is looping over values from 1 to n, we are computing how we can get from 1 to 2, using internal vertices less than 1, less than 2, less than 2 and so on. Now let's say k = 5. This would mean we are trying to compute all the paths from 1 to 2, where the internal vertices are less than or equal to 5. Why is this wrong?

Comment: For your reference: [Why doesn't the Floyd-Warshall algorithm work if I put k in the innermost loop](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9636/4287)

Answer (score 2):

The pseudocode came from Wikipedia and the explanation is in Wikipedia as well. The recurrence is
$dist(i, j, k) = min(dist(i,j,k-1),\ dist(i,k,k-1) + dist(k,j,k-1))$ with the base case $dist(i, j, 0) = w(i, j)$. There is only one way we can achieve this iteratively, by calculating all cases of $k-1$ before calculating cases of $k$. The other answer has an example when this is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you change the order of loops from $k,i,j$ to $i,j,k$. Let's see what happens when $i=1$ and $j=2$:

```
for k from 1 to |V|
  if dist[1][2] > dist[1][k] + dist[k][2]
    dist[1][2] ← dist[1][k] + dist[k][2]
  end if
end for
```

It is not too hard to check that this puts in `dist[1][2]` the value
$$
\min_{1 \leq k \leq |V|} w(1,k) + w(k,2),
$$
where $w(1,1) = w(2,2) = 0$. This is the cost of the shortest path of length at most $2$ from $1$ to $2$.

The $(1,2)$'th iteration is the only one which modifies `dist[1][2]`, so at the end of the procedure, `dist[1][2]` will still contain
$$
\min_{1 \leq k \leq |V|} w(1,k) + w(k,2),
$$
which could be arbitrarily off from the real shortest path from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Okay, so what I don't get is the following sentence: "This is the cost of the shortest path of length at most 2", Why? (1,k) and (k,2) could be paths longer than 2 right?

Comment: No. At this point in the execution, `dist[i][j]` contains $w(i,j)$ (if $i \neq j$) or $0$ (if $i=j$).

Comment: Ahhhh, I see why this fails. So then if k is in the outer loop, how are we avoiding this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I am taking some time to comment, I am trying to read again and again to understand it.

Comment: I point you to the correctness proof of the algorithm. There is no need to repeat it here. The correctness proof explains why the algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the loops in the Floyd-Warshall algorithm is crucial. The algorithm works by progressively improving an estimate of the shortest path between every pair of vertices by considering each vertex as a possible intermediate step on the path.

If you change the order of the loops such that k (the intermediate vertex) is considered last, the algorithm will not work correctly. This is because when you calculate dist[i][j], you're assuming that you've already considered all possible intermediate vertices that could provide a shorter path. If k is considered last, then you're not actually considering all possible intermediate vertices before updating dist[i][j].

So, altering the order of loops to i, j, k will not yield the correct shortest paths between all pairs of vertices. The correct order is k, i, j as in the original Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

Comment: This answer is less precise than the existing ones.